# JQuery plugin class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, plugins

I am developing a JQuery plugin. I need to use OOP inside my plugin. However, the class not working as I expected. When I initiate a new instance of the class, it is only the first line of its code that is executing. What is wrong with this code and how to execute a constructor of this class on initiation?

```
(function ($) {
  var FunClass;

  FunClass = function () {
    console.log("FunGlobal");

    function FunClass() {
      console.log("FunConstructor");
    }

    FunClass.prototype.letsFun = function () {
      console.log("FunMethod");
    }
  }();

  $.fn.fun = function () {
    var funClass;

    return this.each(function () {
        funClass = new FunClass();
        funClass.letsFun();
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Here is the console output: [Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7VU4.png)

Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you initiate a new instance of the class?

Comment: Let's be clear here, you do not have a class - you have a function, which is an object. All methods of an object should be declared on the prototype of the function and not written into the body of the constructor function itself.

Comment: I used this code as the example: [link](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/blob/master/jquery.treetable.js). There is used such a method (Node and Tree). As you said @ScottMarcus i should declare all method on the prototype? Then how i should call constructor for this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you've forgot to return `FunClass`:

```js
(function($) {
  var FunClass;

  FunClass = (function() {
    console.log("FunGlobal");

    function FunClass() {
      console.log("FunConstructor");
    }

    FunClass.prototype.letsFun = function() {
      console.log("FunMethod");
    }
    return FunClass; // you missed this line
  })();

  $.fn.fun = function() {
    var funClass;

    return this.each(function() {
      funClass = new FunClass();
      funClass.letsFun();
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

// Usage
$(function() {
  $('body').fun();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```